# Concatenate a print from a function with a seperate print statement

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have the following function:

```
def string_function(word):
    print(word)
```

How do I make it so that if I call a separate print function, I can concatenate the string from that function to the new print?

E.g. the following will raise a TypeError, but it's what I'm trying to do. :

```
print("foo") + string_function("bar")
```

I know that I can just change the print into a return, but I'm asking if it's possible with a print.

Comment: it would be better if your function returns something instead of printing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `end` argument of the `print` function to display both messages on the same line:

```
print("foo", end="")
string_function("bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` is because neither `print()` nor `string_function()` return anything (except the default return value `None`).

What you are doing here is, essentially, adding `None` with a `None`:

```py
None + None  # This is what causes your TypeError
```

What you probably want is using the `end` argument of `print()` and set it to an empty string:

```py
print("foo", end="")
print("bar")
```

If you want to format or concatenate strings you have several options:

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"

print(f"{a} {b}")        # Use format string
print(a + " " + b)       # Concatenation using +
print(" ".join((a, b)))  # Using str.join
```

Just to name the most common ones.